# ¿Cómo puedo redondear este porcentaje 0.0023556780%?

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Cómo puedo redondear este porcentaje **0.0023556780%** [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca el código con el que imprimes esa cantidad.

Comment: has intentado algo? podrías poner el código de que es lo que llevas :)

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje? Depende de si lo quieres en JavaScript o PHP o HTML5, se hará de una manera o de otra

Answer (score 4):

Probablemente estés usando un framework para los gráifcos. La pregunta es si el porcentaje lo calcula solo o si está en los datos que le pasaste a la librería. Además no es lo mismo (porque no tiene la misma utilidad) redondear a 4 decimales todos los porcentajes que los que son muy bajos.

Yo haría algo así:

```
function redondear(p){
    var DIG_SIG=3;
    var MIN_DIG=0;
    return (p-0).toFixed(Math.max(MIN_DIG,DIG_SIG-Math.log(p)/Math.log(10)));
}

console.log(0.00235567, redondear(0.00235567)) // muestra 0.00236
console.log(0.0123, redondear(0.0123))
console.log(0.9123, redondear(0.9123))
console.log(3.9123, redondear(3.9123)) // muestra 3.91
console.log(53.9123, redondear(53.9123))
console.log(253.9123, redondear(253.9123)) // muestra 254
```

La ventaja de este método es que se pueden elegir la cantidad de dígitos singificativos (en la variable DIG_SIG) y la mínima cantidad de decimales a mostrar (MIN_DIG).

Answer (score 2):

Para redondear, en php puedes usar la función **round()**;

Por ejemplo:

```
$num =  0.0023556780;
echo round($num, 4);
```

como salida mostrará 0.0024;

Answer (score 1):

Desde JavaScript puedes usar la función [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Si la variable ya es un número:

```
> var p = 0.0023556780;
> p.toFixed(4);
"0.0024"
```

Si la variable es una cadena de texto, puedes usar la función [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) para parsear el número:

```
> var p = "0.0023556780";
> parseFloat(p).toFixed(4);
"0.0024"
```